# How to check and delete files that are not same in two different directories in python?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, file, directory

I've two folder and i want to keep the files that are same in both the folders. So now if want to delete the files that are not present in both the folders, with *"the same"* using filenames.

I'm trying this one but it doesn't seems to be working out.

```
dir1 = os.listdir('/home/Desktop/computed_1d/')
dir2 = os.listdir('/home/Desktop/computed_2d_blaze/')

for filename in dir1:
   try:
      for filen in dir2:
         if filename != filen:
           os.remove(filename)
   except:
      pass
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: yep same filename.! @jww

Comment: And do you want to delete the file from the source directory (`dir1`) or the destination directory (`dir2`)? Or both (is that possible?)?

Comment: yeah i wanted to delete files from the source directory but now it worked. @jww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set to check efficiently for the duplicates.

```
dir1 = os.listdir(path1)
dir2 = os.listdir(path2)

duplicates = set(dir1) & set(dir2)

# delete from dir1
for file in dir1:
    if file not in duplicates:
        os.remove(os.path.join(path1,file))

# delete from dir2
for file in dir2:
    if file not in duplicates:
        os.remove(os.path.join(path2,file))
```

Comment: It deleted all of my files.!

Comment: I don't see how it could be possible. Maybe you didn't define well `path1` and `path2`?

Comment: yeah i didn't define the path properly and coz of that it deleted all the files but now it worked. Thanks for the help.!